# Upload a file to S3 compatible service using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using an S3 compatible service. That means my dynamic storage is not hosted on AWS. I found a couple of python scripts that upload files to AWS S3. I would like to do the same but I need to be able to set my own host url. How can that be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Boto3 library (https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for all your S3 needs in Python. To use a custom S3-compatible host instead of the AWS, set the endpoint_url argument when constructing a S3 resource object, e.g.:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session(...)
s3 = session.resource("s3", endpoint_url="http://...", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I wasn't aware that Boto can be used for other providers as well. What needs to be added after the endpoint_url?

Comment: The endpoint would be the address of the S3-compatible service. Their documentation would likely explain how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

You can use amazon route53.

Please refer

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: I don't use AWS. I just need a python code that allows me to provide the host adress as well as the keys.